# cmake find_path doesnot work on windows

Tags: cmake

on my first cmake project it looks like the find_path does not work on windows when im trying to reference package libcurl. im using cmake 2.8.12.2.

i took a look at FindCURL.cmake source code and tried below:

```
if(WIN32)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH 
    "${WIN32_LIBS_DIR}/libcurl" 
    "${WIN32_LIBS_DIR}/libcurl/include" 
    "${WIN32_LIBS_DIR}/libcurl/lib"
    )
find_path(CURL_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES curl/curl.h)   # this line is copied from the first line of FindCURL.cmake source

    message("WIN32_LIBS_DIR: ${WIN32_LIBS_DIR}")
message("thu ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIR}")
```

and get the result of

```
WIN32_LIBS_DIR: ../../../lwqq_root/win32-dev
"thu CURL_INCLUdE_DIR_NOTFOUND",
```

by the way, the variable WIN32_LIBS_DIR is set to win32-dev which looks like below:

```
└─win32-dev
   ├─libcurl
   │  ├─bin
   │  ├─include
   │  │  └─curl
   │  │     └─curl.h
   │  ├─lib
   │  │  └─pkgconfig
   │  └─samples
```

any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried using `find_path(CURL_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES curl.h)` instead?

Comment: This should work.  Are you *certain* that "<...>\win32-dev\libcurl\include\curl\curl.h" exists and that `message("WIN32_LIBS_DIR: ${WIN32_LIBS_DIR}")` shows that `WIN32_LIBS_DIR` is set to the correct path?

Comment: find_path(CURL_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES curl/curl.h)  this line is from the cmake source file, in theory i should not change that. though i just tried and saw the same error.

Comment: WIN32_LIBS_DIR  is absolutely correct.

Comment: I have the same setup as you do (though I am using CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH) and it worked perfectly up until cmake 2.8.12.2. Did you ever solved it? It's still not working in cmake 3.0.

Comment: It's still not working in cmake 3.11.4. Today is July 17, 2018.

Comment: Ran into this problem today trying to compile an old project with Visual Studio. It looks like 3.18 is affected, too.

Comment: The modern way to do this is to `set(CURL_ROOT "${WIN32_LIBS_DIR})` and then `find_package(CURL REQUIRED)`. You can then link to `CURL::libcurl` with `target_link_libraries`. See the docs: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCURL.html

Answer (score 0):

The modern way to use CURL is to use the imported targets created by `FindCURL` and to guide the search with `CURL_ROOT`, like so:

```makefile
set(CURL_ROOT "${WIN32_LIBS_DIR}")
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)

add_executable(my_target main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_target PRIVATE CURL::libcurl)
```

See: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCURL.html

---

Your question does not include enough detail to reproduce your issue. Here is what I did to try:

```makefile
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(test LANGUAGES NONE)

# Create the directory structure in the question:
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/win32-dev/libcurl/bin")
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/win32-dev/libcurl/include/curl")
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/win32-dev/libcurl/lib/pkgconfig")
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/win32-dev/libcurl/samples")

file(WRITE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/win32-dev/libcurl/include/curl/curl.h" "")

# Set WIN32_LIBS_DIR to the root just created
set(WIN32_LIBS_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/win32-dev")

# Your code:
set(
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
  "${WIN32_LIBS_DIR}/libcurl" 
  "${WIN32_LIBS_DIR}/libcurl/include" 
  "${WIN32_LIBS_DIR}/libcurl/lib"
)

find_path(CURL_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES curl/curl.h)

message(STATUS "WIN32_LIBS_DIR: ${WIN32_LIBS_DIR}")
message(STATUS "CURL_INCLUDE_DIR ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIR}")
```

This was on Windows with CMake 3.20, but I am sure it would work going back. I tested this on Linux with *every CMake version* between 3.0 and 3.20 and it worked on *all* of them.

Here's what I see in the terminal:

```
D:\test>cmake -S . -B build
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.19043.
-- WIN32_LIBS_DIR: D:/test/win32-dev
-- CURL_INCLUDE_DIR D:/test/win32-dev/libcurl/include
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/test/build

D:\test>tree /F win32-dev
Folder PATH listing for volume Sources
Volume serial number is 0000008F 943F:828D
D:\TEST\WIN32-DEV
└───libcurl
    ├───bin
    ├───include
    │   └───curl
    │           curl.h
    │
    ├───lib
    │   └───pkgconfig
    └───samples
```

As you can see from the output, I have mirrored your directory layout *exactly* and the same settings of other variables has allowed `find_path` to succeed, even on Windows.